# Shorthand try catch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

Is there a shorthand version of writing something like this:

```
let parsed;

try {
  parsed = JSON.parse(somedata);
} catch (e) {}

someFunction(parsed || {});
```

I'm thinking more in the lines of this:

```
const parsed = try JSON.parse(somedata);

someFunction(parsed || {});
```

Obviously this specific example is super contrived, but I'm curious to know if there is something like it.

Comment: There is no way I know of to shorten down `try`/`catch` blocks. My suggestion is to remove all new-lines and have it inline.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Try/catch oneliner available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126560/try-catch-oneliner-available)