# How to assign const values in error catching code without deep nesting?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this situation

```js
try {
  const foo = await Foo();
} catch (error) {
  console.error(error);
  throw error;
}
```

I have to do a fair amount of stuff with the `foo` variable.

Is there a way I can use the `foo` variable without ending up nested several layers deeper because of try/catch blocks like this? This standard pattern won't work because it's const (and I prefer it to be const):

```js
let x;
try {
  x = await X():
} catch (error) {
  throw error;
}
console.log(x);
```

Comment: Why do you think you would end several layers nested? Can you show in code what do you mean if you would use it in the way that you forsee would cause nesting?

Comment: @Ma3x I just don't want lots of my code an extra layer indented

Comment: So you want a try/catch expression (instead of a statement), but JS does not have one. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126560/try-catch-oneliner-available

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44663864/correct-try-catch-syntax-using-async-await answer your question? Basically either do the "*fair amount of stuff with the `foo` variable*", inside the `try` block, or use `const foo = await Foo().catch(…);`

Comment: Are you catching the "several layers" of promises differently? If not, you could just have one try/catch for all of your await/promise based statements

Comment: I have one solution, but it a way to use it if want to write this kind of code then you can

you can use  "Promise" to assign const variable

     EX:- const data= await new Promice( ()=>{// here yo can handle error or data } )

------if you want complete example  let me Know

Comment: @Bergi `const foo = await Foo().catch(…);` looks like a great solution